# Php Session propagation across pages on cross domain not working

Tags: php, session

Php Session Propagation across pages on cross domain not working

This login form was aimed to use session. It works fine but the session is not propagated
across other pages on a cross domain. it seems session is not set. any help thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#username').focus(); // Focus to the username field on body loads
    $('#login').click(function(){ // Create `click` event function for login
        var username = $('#username'); // Get the username field
        var password = $('#password'); // Get the password field
        var login_result = $('.login_result'); // Get the login result div
        login_result.html('loading..'); // Set the pre-loader can be an animation
        if(username.val() == ''){ // Check the username values is empty or not
            username.focus(); // focus to the filed
            login_result.html('<span class="error">Enter the username</span>');
            return false;
        }
        if(password.val() == ''){ // Check the password values is empty or not
            password.focus();
            login_result.html('<span class="error">Enter the password</span>');
            return false;
        }
        if(username.val() != '' && password.val() != ''){ // Check the username and password values is not empty and make the ajax request
            var UrlToPass = 'action=login&username='+username.val()+'&password='+password.val();
            $.ajax({ // Send the credential values to another checker.php using Ajax in POST menthod
            type : 'POST',
            data : UrlToPass,
            url  : 'http://crossdomain.com/ajax.php',
            success: function(responseText){ // Get the result and asign to each cases
                if(responseText == 0){
                    login_result.html('<span class="error">Username or Password Incorrect!</span>');
                }
                else if(responseText == 1){
                    window.location = 'userpage.php';
                }
                else{
                    alert('Problem with sql query');
                }
            }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>






<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php'; 



if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'login'){
    $username       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
    $query          = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "'.$username.'" AND password = "'.$password.'" ');
    $num_rows       = mysql_num_rows($query); // Get the number of rows
    if($num_rows <= 0){ 
        echo 0;
    } else {
        $fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query);

        $_SESSION['userid']         = $fetch['id'];
        $_SESSION['username']   = $fetch['username'];
        echo 1;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the structure used by your cross domain setup?
Because at the moment we can't help you. Off-topic... I Hope you don't really store plaintext passwords in the database..

Comment: This is what i added in .htaccess file

Comment: Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

Comment: Okay. But you're using multiple domains. A user is authenticating on domain A, then has to be logged in on domain B. If I understood you correctly. How is that relation shown. Are A and B on the same server or different servers. Do A and B have access to each other's cookies/sessions or not. We need details on the configured setup. Not the .htaccess. By your own admission the log in form works. So we need to look somewhere else.

Comment: There is no other configuration. In my local server i have the ajax, html form while in the hosting server, i have the php file. i login from local server via ajax-html form to the hosting/online server

Comment: So you have the form on http://localhost/ you login to http://crossdomain.com/. And then you expect a session on http://localhost/ to hold the values specified by the php script on crossdomain.com?